# php copy() make faster

Tags: php

I'm using php copy() to download a lot of files. But I'd like make this proccess faster. What kind of parameters should I consider? For example, datacenter, connection speed, server memory limit. What would mainly affect on copy() speed?

Comment: better to read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Comment: You're copying remote files? Unless they're very large files, the overhead of setting up/tearing down an http (or ftp, or whatever) connection is going to be the major factor. Consider making a .zip or a .tar of the files on the remote site (if you can) and downloading that one file instead.

Answer (score 3):

- Your connection speed
- Internet latency
- The speed of the connection the server you are downloading from is on
- The load of the server ( both ends )
- The load on the internet connection ( both ends )
- etc...

( The slowness may not be on your end )